# Whenever I input data while logged in to the current user, the data saves for all users. How to save data for the current logged in User only?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authentication

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mood);


    databaseAtrtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Artists");

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddArtist);
    spinnerGenres = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres);
    spinnerEmo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerEmo);
    buttonTips = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTips);

    listViewArtists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArtist);

    listMood = new ArrayList<>();

    mRemoveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeButton);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addAtrist();

        }
    });


    mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            databaseAtrtists.removeValue();
        }
    });


}

private void configureTipsButton() {
    final Button buttonTips = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTips);
    buttonTips.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Mood.this, MoodsTips.class));

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseAtrtists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);


            listMood.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot artistSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                MindYourMood level = artistSnapshot.getValue(MindYourMood.class);
                listMood.add(level);

            }

            MoodLists adaptor = new MoodLists(Mood.this, listMood);
            listViewArtists.setAdapter(adaptor);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void addAtrist() {

    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String emotion = spinnerEmo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String genre = spinnerGenres.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        String id = databaseAtrtists.push().getKey();

        MindYourMood level = new MindYourMood(id, name, emotion, genre);

        databaseAtrtists.child(id).setValue(level);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Emotion Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

---

Above is my code which allows a user to enter data into the firebase database. It saves the data so the current logged in user can view it. However, the issue I have is that, it does not save the data only for the logged in user. Whenever I log in with other users, it displays the same inputted data.

I'm confused on how to fix this.

Any help will be helpful.

*Note - do I need to set something up on the main activity file or is there some code I use for each separate class file to ensure its specific for the current logged in user.

Comment: With so little information to go on it's impossible to say. My guess is though that you're saving the data globally and not tying it to a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this database:

```
Artists
   userId
      artistName: "userX"
      artistEmail: "userx@gmail.com"
   userId
      artistName: "userY"
      artistEmail: "usery@gmail.com"
```

After a user logs in, then you can retrieve his unique userId, and save data under only that id:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();

DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Artists").child(userId);
   ref.child("artistName").setValue("userZ");
   ref.child("artistEmail").setValue("userZ@gmail.com");
```

Here a new user is logged in and his data is saved in the database, under only his id.

Comment: Since the answer helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to the answer, thank you! @user10002755

Comment: I did click on the check mark. Its not showing publicly yet as I'm a new user and my rep is below 15.